# Android.bluetooth.IBluetooth.createBond() not found in 4.2.1 but works in earlier OS versions

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have some code to automatically pair with a bluetooth device by calling createBond(), registering a broadcast receiver for android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST and then manually entering the PIN code to pair.

This has worked great with all devices tested so far up to Andoid 4.0 but today I tried this on my Nexus 7 with Android 4.2.1 and got the following error:

java.lang.noSuchMethodException: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth.createBond

Did they actually remove this function from the library?

**UPDATE**

What's actually happening is the IBluetooth interface object that I am using to call createBond is not being initialized. In the following code the line that tries to get the IBinder named BTBinder returns null when this process fails causing BTInterface to be set to null at the end. So, my question now is why on my Nexus 7 with Android 4.2.1 does the call to get the binder return null but works correctly on 5 other devices I've tested?

```
public static IBluetooth getBluetoothInterface()
{
    //Gets a bluetooth interface from private Android system API
    IBluetooth BTInterface = null;

    try
    {
        Class<?> ServiceManager = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
        Method getService = ServiceManager.getDeclaredMethod("getService", String.class);
        IBinder BTBinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(null, "bluetooth");
        Class<?> IBluetooth = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.IBluetooth");
        Class<?>[] IBluetoothClasses = IBluetooth.getDeclaredClasses();
        Class<?> IBluetoothClass0 = IBluetoothClasses[0];
        Method asInterface = IBluetoothClass0.getDeclaredMethod("asInterface",IBinder.class);
        asInterface.setAccessible(true);
        BTInterface = (IBluetooth) asInterface.invoke(null, BTBinder);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return BTInterface;
}
```

Comment: I'm very interested in tuis problem. If you have some news, please share them :p.

Answer (score 6):

In Android 4.2 they changed the bluetooth stack implementation.

"Android 4.2 introduces a new Bluetooth stack optimized for use with Android devices. The new Bluetooth stack developed in collaboration between Google and Broadcom replaces the stack based on BlueZ and provides improved compatibility and reliability."

There are a lot of bt related things not working even with the public api on Nexus 7.

Comment: Does anyone know where to see the new interfaces?  I use this: http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/  but it does not have 4.2 yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
        throws Exception  
        { 
            Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
            Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");  
            Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
            return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }
```

This worked on 4.2.1 Galaxy Nexus. Haven't tried on Nexus 7, but I had the same issue of MethodNotFoundException when I use IBluetooth method. So it might also fix for Nexus 7 too.